# Spiral Matrix Problem (some range issues)

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a spiral matrix problem with the below code. The Problem is that it's not printing the last element.
The output below is :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11]
```

But it should be :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10]
```

I think I am making some mistake in taking the range but after spending some time I am not able to figure it out. What change should I make to my code to give the output I want?

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
row_start = 0
col_start = 0
row_end = 3
col_end = 3
lis = []
while col_start < col_end and row_start < row_end:

    for i in range(col_start,col_end+1):
        lis.append(arr[row_start][i])

    for i in range(row_start+1,row_end+1):
        lis.append(arr[i][col_end])

    # traverse backwards
    if row_end != row_start+1:
        for i in range(col_end-1,col_start-1,-1):

            lis.append(arr[row_end][i])

    if col_start != col_end+1:
        for i in range(row_end-1,row_start,-1):
            lis.append(arr[i][col_start])

    row_end -= 1
    row_start += 1
    col_start += 1
    col_end -= 1

print(lis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

#### 1

`while col_start < col_end and row_start < row_end:`
should be
`while col_start <= col_end and row_start <= row_end`.
This isn't the current problem because it doesn't matter if your matrix even numbers of both rows and columns, but it is wrong when your matrix has odd number of rows/columns. Think of `arr = [[1]]`.

#### 2

`if row_end != row_start+1:` and `if col_start != col_end+1:`
should be
`if row_end != row_start:` and `if col_start != col_end:`.
Because if `row_end` is `row_start+1`, you can still traverse backwards through the `row_end` row, after going forwards through the `row_start` row.
Think of `arr=[[1,2],[3,4]]`. It's allways good to start small.

So after modifying this, the correct code should be this.

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

row_start = 0
col_start = 0
row_end = 3
col_end = 3
lis = []
while col_start <= col_end and row_start <= row_end:

    for i in range(col_start,col_end+1):
        lis.append(arr[row_start][i])


    for i in range(row_start+1,row_end+1):
        lis.append(arr[i][col_end])


    # traverse backwards
    if row_end != row_start:
        for i in range(col_end-1,col_start-1,-1):

            lis.append(arr[row_end][i])



    if col_start != col_end:
        for i in range(row_end-1,row_start,-1):
            lis.append(arr[i][col_start])

    row_end -= 1
    row_start += 1
    col_start += 1
    col_end -= 1

print(lis)
```

Comment: @MayankNautiyal problem is not solved? What's the new problem?